# String parsing in F# - generated IL

Tags: .net, parsing, f#, il

I have written some small string parsing functions in F# - in order to get a better feel for F# and to see how to solve such tasks with it. I try to walk over a string and search for specific characters via recursion.

The logic does work but the generated IL code of the release build (optimizations turned on) does look kind of weird in my opinion. So I guess there is a better way to write this stuff in a performant way in F#.

This is what part the parsing functions look like:

```
let eatTag (input : string) index =
    let len = input.Length
    let nothing = 0, null, TagType.Open

    // more functions used in the same way
    // ...

    let rec findName i =
        if i >= len then nothing
        else
            let chr = input.[i]
            if isWhitespace chr then
                findName (i+1)
            elif chr = '/' then
                getName (i+1) (i+1) true
            else getName (i+1) i false

    let rec findStart i =
        if i >= len then nothing
        elif input.[i] = '<' then findName (i+1)
        else findStart (i+1)

    findStart index
```

This is what the generated IL code for the findStart function looks like:

```
 // loop start
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.2
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: blt.s IL_000e

    IL_0005: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0006: ldnull
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0008: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Tuple`3<int32, string, valuetype TagType>::.ctor(!0, !1, !2)
    IL_000d: ret

    IL_000e: ldarg.0
    IL_000f: ldarg.2
    IL_0010: call instance char [mscorlib]System.String::get_Chars(int32)
    IL_0015: ldc.i4.s 60
    IL_0017: bne.un.s IL_0024

    IL_0019: ldarg.0
    IL_001a: ldarg.1
    IL_001b: ldarg.2
    IL_001c: ldc.i4.1
    IL_001d: add
    IL_001e: call class [mscorlib]System.Tuple`3<int32, string, valuetype TagType> findName@70(string, int32, int32)
    IL_0023: ret

    IL_0024: ldarg.0
    IL_0025: ldarg.1
    IL_0026: ldarg.2
    IL_0027: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0028: add
    IL_0029: starg.s i
    IL_002b: starg.s len
    IL_002d: starg.s input
    IL_002f: br.s IL_0000
// end loop
```

The C# view (ILSpy) for this function shows the following code - and this is especially the reason why I think I am doing something wrong here. Obviously the function arguments are somehow assigned to itself...?!

```
internal static Tuple<int, string, TagType> findStart@80(string input, int len, int i)
{
        while (i < len)
        {
                if (input[i] == '<')
                {
                        return findName@70(input, len, i + 1);
                }
                string arg_2D_0 = input;
                int arg_2B_0 = len;
                i++;
                len = arg_2B_0;
                input = arg_2D_0;
        }
        return new Tuple<int, string, TagType>(0, null, TagType.Open);
}
```

The same problem can be seen in the other functions that are processed in a continuation-style. Any pointers to what I am either doing or assuming wrong are greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with that code? Just because of a piece of code that basically does nothing that will be most likely optimized out by the JIT compiler?

Comment: @svick: 'basically nothing' is really important here :)

Comment: @svick: Yeah, maybe that is the reason :-) I was just trying to inspect different variations to solve this quite simple task and stumbled over  these instructions that I would not expect to be there. It could be a hint to me as a fairly beginner in F# that I am doing something not perfectly right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is tail call elimination.

The process of removing a tail call and turning the tail call in to a 'jump' to the start of the function. (iow a `while(true) { }` construct).

The reason you see the 'same' assignments is to keep the semantics the same as if you were calling the function normally. It is nigh impossible to determine if 1 assignment could affect another efficiently, hence the use of temporary variables, and then the assignment back to them.

Comment: I see - maybe I just expected the F# compiler would remove these assignments since the values don't change at all.

Comment: @kongo2002: The analysis to determine that is too expensive. And the JIT should do a good enough job of it :)

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, the compiler turns a recursive function into non-recursive in this case. This is only possible when the recursive call appears in a "tail-call" position and if the function calls itself. In general, the compiler has the following options:

- **Compile function as a loop** - when the function calls itself and the call is in tail-call position. This is the most efficient alternative, because it eliminates creating a new stack frame and it uses standard loops.
- **Compile function using `.tail call` IL instruction** - when the call appears in tail-call position, but you're calling a different function (for example, if you have two mutually recursive functions declared using the `let rec foo () = ... and bar () = ...` syntax). This avoids creating a new stack frame (you won't get stack overflow), but it is less efficient, because the `.tail call` instruction in .NET has not been optimized that much.
- **Compile using normal recursion** - when a function calls itself recursively and *then* does some more calculation, the code is compiled using standard recursive call instead of a *tail-call* (and a new stack frame needs to be allocated for every call, so you may get stack overflow)

The optimization that is done in the first case (in your example) looks like this: In general, a tail-recursive function looks something like this:

```
let rec foo x = 
  if condition then 
    let x' = calculateNewArgument x // Run some computation
    foo x'                          // (Tail-)recursively calls itself
  else 
    calculateResult x               // Final calculation in the branch that returns
```

The code is translated to the following loop that stores the argument in a mutable variable:

```
let foo x = 
  let mutable x = x
  while condition do                // Check condition using current argument value
    x <- calculateNewArgument x     // Instead of recursion, run next iteration
  calculateResult x                 // Final calculation in the branch that returns
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. On top of that I am curious why the F# compiler assigns the function arguments on every loop iteration although they are value types that would not change its value.

Comment: @kongo2002 Eliminating that additional assignment would make sense - it could be done if the F# compiler had some more complicated analysis for checking what variables are assigned to, but it simply is not implemented (in general, it may need to re-assign all arguments). I think there is a fair chance that the JIT compiler will eliminate such assignments.

Comment: "This is only possible..." Strictly speaking, it is always possible. http://www.amazon.com/Compiling-Continuations-Andrew-W-Appel/dp/052103311X

Answer (score 2):

Basically, instead of creating a chain like

```
findstart(findstart(findstart(findstart.....
```

the compiler converts to a loop which eliminates the function calls.

This is [Tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), a pretty standard functional programming optimisation.  This works as the overhead of reasignning to the argunments to a function is lower than calling a new function which generates a new stack frame.

Comment: It is called tail call elimination. The tail call got removed and the recursive call is now simply a jump to the start of the function. There is no formal such thing called tail call optimization unless you specifically talking about space complexity.

Comment: Also, you `chain` example is very much not tail recursive. A tail call can only appear alongside a `return`. So `return foo( return foo ( ...`  is not possible.

Comment: what about if `let ref f a = if a=0 then a else a-1` - as a chain is `f(f(f(f(4))))`

Comment: But that is not even a recursive function ;p And chaining it does not make it recursive, nevermind tail recursive :)